# Renaming a WP7 Application that has already been deployed to the MarketPlace, Existing Data?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a WP7 App in the MarketPlace and I want to rename this app as its existing name clashes with an existing website.  If I publish the App  with the new name to the marketplace will the existing settings a files in Isolated Storage continue to work with the new app with the different name?  I want to make sure that existing users wont loose any data if I change the apps name.

Comment: There might be another issue: As long as you don't notify the users of your "new" app, the will never know that they should switch to your new app.

Comment: Indeed and its extra hastle for users

Comment: @JonAlb I sent you a message via your blog. I have a Marketplace contact who might be able to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the name displayed on the phone. However, re-naming the "title" on the marketplace is a no-go.

It's been somewhat possible in the past, but with the new AppHub it's most definitively not possible anymore.

Comment: I think the disparity between an AppName on the phone and MarketPlace name would be less than ideal.  Im starting to think I should leave the App under its orginal name, and keep the website with the new name as it is a differntiator.  The other option would be to double publish the same app under both names but that also messy.  If only you could change an existing marketplace name.

Comment: Yeah, that's a better approach. My experience tells me that users don't care much for the name.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you're out of luck. Resubmitting you application with a new name will be a new application (AFAICT there is not a clear way around that), so it won't have access to the isolated storage for a different application.

Maybe you can consider submitting an upgrade to the existing application that will transfer the data somewhere (post to a web service or some such), in conjunction with your new application that can retrieve that information on a one-time basis.

Best luck!

Comment: It sounds like I cannot change the marketplace name without a republish.... However the other answer suggests I can change app name as it appears on the phone and the isolated storage will continue to work (but there will be a naming difference between marketplace name and the name on the phone).  I think the webservice  upload is a good idea but hastle for users if they neeed to download a separate app.  I am still not 100% sure what happens if I submit a XAP with different app name within it, and trying it out on a live app seems a little risky.